# Command 'Go' not found after installing on WSL with Ubuntu 20.04. Go is in $PATH

Tags: bash, environment-variables, golang

I've been struggling with this (seemingly) straightforward installation. If I run `echo $PATH` I get the following as part of the output `/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/go-1.19.2/bin`. What's even more interesting is that I am able to run `sudo /usr/local/go/bin/go version` and it works. But `go version` doesn't.

Here's a detailed description of everything I've done so far:

I installed go by following the exact instructions on the website. I then tried to `mv` into /usr/local/ but I encountered a weird [error](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3967) that I couldn't figure out. I then simply used `cp` to move the directory. Then I added the export Path command in my `.profile` as directed. Command 'go' not found.

I've tried adding PATH to `.bashrc`, I've tried exporting GOPATH, GOROOT, and various other things suggested in other threads. Nothing seems to work. I then scrubbed everything clean and started again, removing any extra go PATH variables. Still nothing.

Please Help.

Comment: You may answer your own question, and if upvoted, accept it in a few days, getting it marked as "solved", gaining some rep. points, and helping others.

Comment: @ubfan1 Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. For SOME reason, the go folder in `/usr/local` was not executable. Changed the file permissions, and it's working now. Leaving this question here in case someone else finds this useful.